# Get the standard context menu for System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox

Tags: winforms, richtextbox, contextmenu

How can I get the standard context menu in a RichTextBox, like the one in TextBox (Copy, Paste, IME etc.)? I'd go with a P/Invoke solution if nothing is available out of the box. Or do I really have to follow those strange advices to create a custom menu to get a standard menu (*sigh*)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ContextMenuStrip` property of the richtextbox can be assigned to a user designed context menu, Copy/Cut/Paste and just apply the RichTextBox's methods to each of the menu items such as CanUndo, CanCopy, CanPaste to determine the menu item's `Enabled` property. Using the methods 'Copy`,`Cut`and`Paste` will be the executed method for the menu item's click event.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: It should be noted that the TextBox does indeed have their own standard context menu, by assigning null to it prevents the user from copying/pasting etc...

Comment: Unfortunately, that's just a custom context menu which I'd rather not have to create, especially with the more complicated options like IME and Insert Unicode Character etc. The mention of the Can* properties is a good advice, though, so +1 for that. I guess I'll do that when nobody can tell me how to get the standard menu. I'd really like to have the TextBox standard menu on a RichTextBox. Seems impossible, though, unfortunately.

Comment: See here for an example of an extended RichtextBox.. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/richtextboxextended.aspx
I wouldn't go far to implementing an IME and insert unicode character as that would be pinvoke involved...

Comment: Interesting thing. We're using the Krypton Toolkit in this particular project, though, so the RichTextBox is already encapsulated and I think we can't change the underlying class. On the other hand, the Krypton styling is just a thin border for a RichTextBox...

Comment: I've accepted this answer for now. It seems to be the only way. The codeproject article is a convenient short-cut, but it's basically the same you already suggested.

Comment: Today, I implemented this solution. It works, though CanCopy does not exist. I checked (SelectionLength > 0) instead for cut, copy and delete. I also had problems with the short-cuts not working properly because some other component in the main window blocked them. But it's fine now ;)